# Rails: sort collection with scope using one of two dates

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to write a scope that sorts on one of two columns--if the first (`scheduled_at`) has data in it then use that data, otherwise resort to `created_at`.

```
def self.by_scheduled_at
  if scheduled_at
    order(scheduled_at: :desc)
  else
    order(created_at: :desc) 
  end  
end
```

This code fails because `scheduled_at` is an instance attribute and this is a class method.

How can I write this scope so it sorts the collection based on whether `scheduled_at` is present?

Comment: Whether `scheduled_at` is present *on what*? The class? Could you show us how you intend to call this?

Comment: Make it not class? Or call it on a member passed in? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you mean to sort by whether created_at or sorted_at is present *in each row*. That is if sorted_at has a value, use that. But if it's nil, use created_at.

| sorted_at | created_at |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 2030-01-01 |
| null | 2020-02-02 |
| 2020-03-03 | null |
| 2020-04-04 | 1999-01-01 |

For that you'd use [`coalesce`](https://learnsql.com/blog/coalesce-function-sql/); it returns the first non-null value. Then write it as a [scope](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes).

```
scope :by_scheduled_at, -> { order("coalesce(scheduled_at, created_at) DESC") }
```

Comment: I'm going to mark this one as accepted despite using the information from both--I needed the `Arel.sq()` wrap to avoid an error, but this one is more general given the fact that I use Postgres. Thanks so much!

Comment: @t56k Did you get an error? [The docs say that should be ok](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-order). "*This could be a source of SQL injection, so only strings composed of plain column names and simple function(column_name) expressions with optional ASC/DESC modifiers are allowed.*"

Answer (score 1):

If you want a chainable scope, something like this should work (tested on MySQL, via the `mysql2` gem):

```rb
scope :by_scheduled_at, -> { order(Arel.sql("IFNULL(scheduled_at, created_at) DESC")) }
```

As noted by @Schwern, `IFNULL` is MySQL specific, use `COALESCE` for standard SQL (implemented also by SQLite and PostgreSQL).

Comment: Note: `ifnull` is not standard SQL, it's MySQL specific. The standard SQL is `coalesce`. [MySQL implements `coalesce`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce), there's no reason to use `ifnull`.